# Passing array of pointers to (char) to a function and assigning a string to each

Tags: c, arrays, string, function, pointers

What i´m trying to do is assigning strings to pointers in a vector from a separate function for that use. unfortunately i keep getting either a lot of warnings or errors or bus trap:10.

here´s the code so far here i commented where i´m having issues:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void read_top(FILE **read,short int *L, short int *D, short int *N){
    fscanf(*read,"%hd %hd %hd",L,D,N); // L being the size of the strings, D being how many strings there are and N doesn´t matter for this question
    fgetc(*read); // remove \n
}

void save_words(FILE **read,char **dic,short int L,short int D){ // i´m having problems here assigning strings to the pointers
    int e;
    for (e = 0;e < D;e++){
        *dic[e] = malloc(125);
        fgets(*dic[e],L+1,*read);
        fgetc(*read);
    }
}

void open(FILE **read,FILE **write) {
    *read = fopen("teste4.in","r");
    *write = fopen("Allien_language","w");
}

void alloc(char **dic,D,L){ //i´m having problems here allocating memory for each pointer to point to 
    int e;
    for (e = 0;e < D; e++){
        *dic[e] = malloc(L);
    }
}

main(){
    FILE *read,*write;
    open(&read,&write);
    short int L,D,N;
    read_top(&read,&L,&D,&N);
    char *dic[D]; // here´s the array of pointers
    alloc(dic,D,L); // here´s the funtion i can´t get to work
    save_words(&read,dic,L,D); // here´s the function that i can´t get to work
    //printf("\n%s\n",dic[0]);
}
```

I´ve tried multiple things, but i think the main problem is not knowing exactly how things work. this includes passing the array to the function and assigning the strings to it and allocating the memory for each pointer.           I´ve also been searching in this site for my questions, where i found solutions to similar problems but didn´t understand exactly their solutions. If someone could explain me exactly how things should work i would appreciate that.

thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you passing around the `FILE` pointer using a pointer to it? It's only needed to emulate pass by reference for your `open` function, in the other functions it's just extra unneeded indirection.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg      So that next time I'm in the place of the file i want to be in and not at the beginning or behind than what i want it to be. I think that's how it works though. Either way that works fine but i would appreciate a clarification on that now that you mention it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do e.g. `*dic[e] = malloc(...)` you're doing it wrong. What the expression `*dic[e]` does is get element `e` of the array `dic`, which is a pointer to `char`, then you *dereference* the pointer giving you the value of what `dic[e]` is pointing to. Unfortunately `dic[e]` doesn't point anywhere yet, which would lead to *undefined behavior* and a probable crash if the compiler didn't give you an error.

And you get an error because you try to assign the pointer returned by `malloc` to something that's not a pointer.

So the solution? Remove the dereference, and just do e.g. `dic[e] = malloc(...)`.

You have the same problem when you try to read the string from the file in `save_words`. And there you have another problem, you allocate memory for the string *again*, making you loose the original allocation from the `alloc` function, and leading to a memory leak.

Comment: Thank you i now understand what i was doing wrong and that memory leak problem... I had no clue about that. I'm sure i can keep doing what i was doing now.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are treating elements of the array of pointers incorrectly: rather than assigning

```
*dic[e] = malloc(L);
```

you should be assigning

```
dic[e] = malloc(L);
```

without the dereference operator.

The reason for this is that you are passing an array of uninitialized pointers, so you may not dereference them. However, you can certainly assign them, which is what `dic[e] = malloc(L)` does.

You have the same problem in `save_words`. The fix is even simpler there - you need to drop the `*dic[e] = malloc(125);` line, because it re-assigns a pointer that has been assigned already.

Finally, you need to remove dereference operator from this line as well:

```
fgets(dic[e],L+1,*read); // No asterisk in front of "dic[e]"
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation